# Svg animate: begin and end

Tags: html, css, svg

I am studying about svg animatepoint. I want a circle zoom to radius=80 and after that change back to 60. I saw the msdn and use the begin and .end method.

It work for Firefox but fail in google chrome.
In google chrome, it will change the radius to 80 (ZoomAct)and stop. It haven't run the (NarrowAct) animate.

How to solve it?

```
<circle r="60" cx="200" cy="200"  id = "AnimatePoint"
            style="fill:rgba(18, 66, 243 , 0.3);stroke:blue;stroke-width:4;display:block">

        <animate id = ZoomAct
                    attributeName="r" 
                    from="60" to="80" 
                    dur="1s" 
                    begin ="0s;NarrowAct.end"
        />  
        <animate id = NarrowAct
                    attributeName="r" 
                    from="80" to="60" 
                    dur="1s" 
                    begin="ZoomAct.end"
        />  
    </circle>
```

JSFIDDLE LINK:
http://jsfiddle.net/kimwong/mwxj220f/

**Update by 2015/1/15**

**Finally I found out the problem, it is not relate to the double quotes. I have added the double quotes in my local file it fails again.
The problem is that i included two js library:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

**When i remove one of the .js file. It works.**

There is the fail case after i add those two library in fiddle.net:
It will zoom one time and stop.
**http://jsfiddle.net/kimwong/mwxj220f/2/**

Any one can have another ways to finish this animation?

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome and Firefox. Your `id`s should have double quotes `"` around it. ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwxj220f/1/).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for i forgot to type the double quotes. but i think the problem is no here. The animate still fail in Google chrome when i open it in my local file. it works in fiddle.

Comment: If you can't provide a testcase that demonstrates the issue, we likely can't help you.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you. I have update the question and new fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the quotes around your ids ("ZoomAct" and "NarrowAct").

When you are inlining it in an HTML page (as with the jsfiddle), the browser is using the more lenient HTML parsing rules.  But in the standalone case it is using XML parsing rules which require that your attributes have quotes.

In fact, Chrome tells you exactly that when you load it.

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 9 at column 15: AttValue: " or ' expected Below is a
>   rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But the problem is not the double quotes in this problem. I have update the question. Please check it. :)